# Bug in iOS 9 when using client SSL certs and generating HTTP 403 errors

Tags: ios, ssl, http-status-code-403, client-certificates, app-transport-security

I think we just discovered a bug on iOS 9 (version as of Oct 23rd 2015) when using client SSL certs to talk to a backend API.   In common with a lot of REST services, our API generates 4xx error codes to communicate status.  One of those is a 403 Forbidden error when a client tries to access paths that a specific client ID is not authorized to access.   Note that this HTTP error occurs AFTER the client SSL cert has setup a valid connection & and the client ID has been authenticated.

In iOS 9, this sequence will generate an invalid client SSL error:

`FAILED: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1206 "The server “our.server.here” requires a client certificate."`

(note: this a followup to my tweet here: https://twitter.com/ckmaresca/status/657576686318256128 - I figured SO is the place most people will search for this)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It took us days to finally figure out but it turns out that this particular error is generated by Apple's new Application Transport Layer security.  Specifically, it seems that if you are using client certs and your backend API generates an HTTP 403 error, ATL believes that the cert is bad and kills the entire transaction.

We know this because we can see in our server logs that the request goes through and executes properly. We've also observed that the socket stays alive trough the request and this error only shows up after the response from the server is received.   We also know our client cert works since any path not returning a 403 works with zero errors and changing the HTTP error code to 401 makes this problem go away.

This is problematic for a number of reasons, but mostly because HTTP errors are not SSL errors.  The two can operate independently and it's perfectly possible to have a 403 error with a valid client side SSL certificate....

The work around is to change all your 403 errors to something else.  I would note that a large number of Oauth1/2 servers will generate various 403 errors, so this might be non-trivial.  Alternatively, it might be possible to use a reverse proxy to remap HTTP 403 errors to a different HTTP code - we have not tested this.

We have filed a bug with Apple, but I wanted to give people a heads up so maybe they can avoid banging their heads against a wall like we did for a week....

Thanks to the [Sherbit.io](https://www.sherbit.io) enginnering team (specifically Varun & Matt) for debugging this.

Comment: Hey @ckm, I'm having the exact same issue and spent days on it. What solution did you end up using? I can't control the server to not return 403. :( Did you find any workaround?

Comment: Can you also paste the rdar link please?

Comment: @ckm, We are still having the same issue, Any update on the radar?

Comment: No updates, sorry.  Is the bug still present in iOS10/11?  We solved it by changing the HTTP error code on return.

Comment: Would be great to know if this is resolved in iOS 10/11

Comment: I don't know, sorry.  It's pretty easy to test if you are developing iOS apps and have access to a webserver....

Comment: Thanks, @ckm. We encounter the same problem in iOS 13.4. Apple still not fix the bug. Once we replace the 403 code on return, the iOS app works just fine.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. But my request does not reach the API server instead it fails at the device end and it is showing the same "requires client certificate" error. Any help on this?

Comment: @ashok, sorry for the late reply just saw this.  I would suggest breaking down the transaction like I outlined in the 2nd paragraph and testing everything, logging as much detail as you can.  Also check any proxies or WAFs that might be inbetween the API & client device.